# ubuntu 12.04 sssd sudo not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ldap, sssd

This is for Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

I am trying to implement SSSD as a client and everything works all right BUT SUDO
I cannot see anything happening in the sssd_sudo.log file at all but the usual file refresh

Installed versions:

- sudo-ldap : Version: 1.8.3p1-1ubuntu3.7
- sssd: Version: 1.8.6-0ubuntu0.3
- nscd: Version: 2.15-0ubuntu10.11
- libsss-sudo: Version: 1.11.7-3

I can see in the logs sssd is searching within the sudoers in the ldap server. (note is is a freeIPA 4.1 ldap server and This implementation is using PLANE sssd so nothing ipa related in the ubuntu client box)

Configs:

nsswitch.conf

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

# passwd:         compat sss
# pre_auth-client-config # passwd:   compat
passwd:   compat sss
# group:          compat sss
# pre_auth-client-config # group:    compat
group:    compat sss
# shadow:         compat
# pre_auth-client-config # shadow:   compat
shadow:   compat

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files
sudoers:    files sss

sudoers_debug: 1

# netgroup:       nis sss
# pre_auth-client-config # netgroup: nis
netgroup: nis
```

sssd.conf

```
[sssd]
debug_level = 5
config_file_version = 2
reconnection_retries = 3
sbus_timeout = 30
#services = nss, pam
services = nss,pam,sudo

domains = corp.company.com

[nss]
debug_level = 9
reconnection_retries = 3
entry_cache_nowait_percentage = 50

[pam]
debug_level = 9
reconnection_retries = 3
offline_failed_login_attempts = 5
offline_failed_login_delay = 5

[domain/corp.company.com]

ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/ldap/cacerts/389.crt

enumerate = True
#min_id = 200
debug_level = 5
ldap_tls_reqcert = demand
ldap_id_use_start_tls = True
cache_credentials = True
ldap_uri = ldaps://freeipa.server.com

#auth_provider = krb5
#chpass_provider = ldap
#krb5_realm = corp.company.com

auth_provider = ldap
id_provider = ldap
access_provider = simple
ldap_search_base = dc=corp,dc=company,dc=com
ldap_schema = rfc2307
ldap_user_search_base = cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=corp,dc=company,dc=com
ldap_group_search_base = cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=corp,dc=company,dc=com
ldap_default_bind_dn = uid=specialuser,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=corp,dc=company,dc=com
ldap_default_authtok_type = obfuscated_password
ldap_default_authtok = <password>

sudo_provider = ldap
ldap_sudo_search_base = ou=sudoers,DC=corp,DC=company,DC=com

[sudo]
debug_level = 9
```

log_files

sssd_sudo.log

```
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sss_process_init] (0x0020): Responder Initialization complete
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sudo_process_init] (0x0400): SUDO Initialization complete
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): dbus conn: 7BEB40
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): dbus conn: 7BEB40
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): dbus conn: 7C0FE0
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): dbus conn: 7C0FE0
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_toggle_watch] (0x4000): 0x7bde20/0x7bb700 (13), R/- (disabled)
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_toggle_watch] (0x4000): 0x7bde20/0x7bb6b0 (13), -/W (enabled)
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_toggle_watch] (0x4000): 0x7c1570/0x7c0b60 (14), R/- (disabled)
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_toggle_watch] (0x4000): 0x7c1570/0x7c0b10 (14), -/W (enabled)
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_toggle_watch] (0x4000): 0x7bde20/0x7bb700 (13), R/- (enabled)
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_toggle_watch] (0x4000): 0x7bde20/0x7bb6b0 (13), -/W (disabled)
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_toggle_watch] (0x4000): 0x7c1570/0x7c0b60 (14), R/- (enabled)
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_toggle_watch] (0x4000): 0x7c1570/0x7c0b10 (14), -/W (disabled)
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_toggle_watch] (0x4000): 0x7bde20/0x7bb700 (13), R/- (disabled)
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_toggle_watch] (0x4000): 0x7bde20/0x7bb6b0 (13), -/W (enabled)
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_toggle_watch] (0x4000): 0x7c1570/0x7c0b60 (14), R/- (disabled)
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_toggle_watch] (0x4000): 0x7c1570/0x7c0b10 (14), -/W (enabled)
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_toggle_watch] (0x4000): 0x7bde20/0x7bb700 (13), R/- (enabled)
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_toggle_watch] (0x4000): 0x7bde20/0x7bb6b0 (13), -/W (disabled)
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_toggle_watch] (0x4000): 0x7c1570/0x7c0b60 (14), R/- (enabled)
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_toggle_watch] (0x4000): 0x7c1570/0x7c0b10 (14), -/W (disabled)
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_remove_timeout] (0x2000): 0x7be830
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): dbus conn: 7BEB40
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [id_callback] (0x0100): Got id ack and version (1) from Monitor
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_remove_timeout] (0x2000): 0x7c1a10
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): dbus conn: 7C0FE0
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [dp_id_callback] (0x0100): Got id ack and version (1) from DP
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:36 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): dbus conn: 7BEB40
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:36 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:36 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_message_handler] (0x4000): Received SBUS method [ping]
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:46 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): dbus conn: 7BEB40
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:46 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:46 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_message_handler] (0x4000): Received SBUS method [ping]
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:56 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): dbus conn: 7BEB40
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:56 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
    (Thu Mar 26 20:47:56 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_message_handler] (0x4000): Received SBUS method [ping]
    (Thu Mar 26 20:48:06 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): dbus conn: 7BEB40
    (Thu Mar 26 20:48:06 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
    (Thu Mar 26 20:48:06 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_message_handler] (0x4000): Received SBUS method [ping]
    (Thu Mar 26 20:48:16 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): dbus conn: 7BEB40
    (Thu Mar 26 20:48:16 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
    (Thu Mar 26 20:48:16 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_message_handler] (0x4000): Received SBUS method [ping]
    (Thu Mar 26 20:48:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): dbus conn: 7BEB40
    (Thu Mar 26 20:48:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
    (Thu Mar 26 20:48:26 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_message_handler] (0x4000): Received SBUS method [ping]
    (Thu Mar 26 20:48:36 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): dbus conn: 7BEB40
    (Thu Mar 26 20:48:36 2015) [sssd[sudo]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.

sudo_domain.log

(Thu Mar 26 21:03:50 2015) [sssd[be[corp.company.com]]] [sssm_simple_access_init] (0x0020): No rules supplied for simple access provider. Access will be granted for all users.
(Thu Mar 26 21:03:50 2015) [sssd[be[corp.company.com]]] [load_backend_module] (0x0200): no module name found in confdb, using [ldap].
(Thu Mar 26 21:03:50 2015) [sssd[be[corp.company.com]]] [load_backend_module] (0x0200): no module name found in confdb, using [ldap].
(Thu Mar 26 21:03:50 2015) [sssd[be[corp.company.com]]] [common_parse_search_base] (0x0100): Search base added: [SUDO][ou=sudoers,DC=corp,DC=company,DC=com][SUBTREE][]
(Thu Mar 26 21:03:50 2015) [sssd[be[corp.company.com]]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0200): Option ldap_sudorule_object_class has value sudoRole
(Thu Mar 26 21:03:50 2015) [sssd[be[corp.company.com]]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0200): Option ldap_sudorule_name has value cn
(Thu Mar 26 21:03:50 2015) [sssd[be[corp.company.com]]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0200): Option ldap_sudorule_command has value sudoCommand
(Thu Mar 26 21:03:50 2015) [sssd[be[corp.company.com]]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0200): Option ldap_sudorule_host has value sudoHost
(Thu Mar 26 21:03:50 2015) [sssd[be[corp.company.com]]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0200): Option ldap_sudorule_user has value sudoUser
(Thu Mar 26 21:03:50 2015) [sssd[be[corp.company.com]]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0200): Option ldap_sudorule_option has value sudoOption
(Thu Mar 26 21:03:50 2015) [sssd[be[corp.company.com]]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0200): Option ldap_sudorule_runasuser has value sudoRunAsUser
(Thu Mar 26 21:03:50 2015) [sssd[be[corp.company.com]]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0200): Option ldap_sudorule_runasgroup has value sudoRunAsGroup
(Thu Mar 26 21:03:50 2015) [sssd[be[corp.company.com]]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0200): Option ldap_sudorule_notbefore has value sudoNotBefore
(Thu Mar 26 21:03:50 2015) [sssd[be[corp.company.com]]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0200): Option ldap_sudorule_notafter has value sudoNotAfter
(Thu Mar 26 21:03:50 2015) [sssd[be[corp.company.com]]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0200): Option ldap_sudorule_order has value sudoOrder
(Thu Mar 26 21:03:50 2015) [sssd[be[corp.company.com]]] [load_backend_module] (0x0200): no module name found in confdb, using [ldap].
(Thu Mar 26 21:03:50 2015) [sssd[be[corp.company.com]]] [ldap_get_autofs_options] (0x0200): Option ldap_autofs_search_base set to dc=corp,dc=company,dc=com
(Thu Mar 26 21:03:50 2015) [sssd[be[corp.company.com]]] [common_parse_search_base] (0x0100): Search base added: [AUTOFS][dc=corp,dc=company,dc=com][SUBTREE][]
(Thu Mar 26 21:03:50 2015) [sssd[be[corp.company.com]]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0200): Option ldap_autofs_map_object_class has value automountMap
(Thu Mar 26 21:03:50 2015) [sssd[be[corp.company.com]]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0200): Option ldap_autofs_map_name has value ou
(Thu Mar 26 21:03:50 2015) [sssd[be[corp.company.com]]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0200): Option ldap_autofs_entry_object_class has value automount
```

Comment: I know this question is a bit old, but it did come up as one of the top links in my google search on the issue I figured this might help others as well. https://lists.fedorahosted.org/pipermail/sssd-users/2013-November/001168.html

Answer (score 1):

First, SSSD 1.8 is very old and not supported by upstream anymore. I hope this is a vendor-supported distribution.

About sudo, I didn't see a request coming from sudo in the sssd_sudo log. In this old version you had to manually install libsss_sudo IIRC, you might want to check if that's the case on ubuntu, too.

Finally, I don't understand why do you use id_provider=ldap with an IPA server and not id_provider=ipa (as set up by ipa-client-install). Your hand-crafted configuration is incorrect, at least the schema should not be set to rfc2307, your group memberships will not work as IPA uses a variant of the rfc2307bis schema. You should also not use enumerate=True for performance reasons.

Comment: In the end I completely dumped IPA as it got a number of issues which affected the whole stability of the setup. The product was still a bit immature for my purpose.
I do really appreciate your comments.